# how to give background position in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I trying to give background-position in jquery, but it is not working.

```
var a = 20;
var b = 30; 
var loader_pos = a + b;

$('.loader-search').css({"background-position" : center loader_pos});
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which bowser ? some brosers need to append px.

Comment: In chrome & firefox, also tried with px

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*but it is not working*"?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function RTFM

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.loader-search').css({"background-position" : "center "+loader_pos+"px"});
```

Try this out.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gmbuLmxx/)

Comment: @InderjeetSinghAhuja see the demo its working now :)

Comment: Thanks Kawinesh, I have made a mistake in variable calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.loader-search').css({"background-position" :loader_pos + "px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2v6hbma/3/)

html

```
<div class="check"></div>
```

jquesy

```
 $('.check').hover(function()
                  {
                  var a = 20;
var b = 30; 
var loader_pos = a + b;
                  $(this).css('background-position','center,'+loader_pos+'px');
                  });
```

css

```
.check
{
height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:url('http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/179/2/c/ios_7_icons__updated__by_iynque-d69mme1.png');
}
```